# DLL support after the process ends

Tags: c++

I have a small application. Depending on command line arguments, it loads or frees a library that filters system level input. Once the library is loaded, will it stay active after the process dies, or does the application need to stay alive in the background?

Comment: You might want to clarify (for yourself) what does it mean for dll to be "active".

Comment: This may extend the original question, but in the case of what i am doing: (windows 7) i am loading a dll, i am setting a windows hook (pointer to the address of a function) and that hook is set to a call back function which filters system internal signals.

Comment: Im setting the hook in the process that dies shortly after. Does the hook disappear with the process?

Comment: Hook will disappear after you explicitly unhook it or after your main application terminates (technically it will also won't be working after application you hook into is terminated, but hook state will still exist in parent process). Note that when you hook into another application dll will be loaded into that application.

Comment: Ahh... looks like i have to keep my process alive and put ipc back in... darn. I was hoping i could pull a fast one and pass cmd line args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process dies everything it did dies with it - that includes threads it created, things it loaded into memory (like DLLs for example), memory it allocated, etc. Some differences exist between operating systems, but that's the general gist of it - your process terminates; it is gone along with everything it did (with exceptions like sysv shared memory, other global resources that may have been manipulated etc, but in most respects; when your process is pushing up daisies there's nothing left).

Comment: Does that count for hook procedures as well?

Comment: @Mike AFAIK your hook will die with the process.

Answer (score 0):

Dll may stay in memory even after process is terminated. For example it may be loaded into another process or just cached. However note that entire dll state, including all the objects and data handled by the code from that dll, is completely gone because that state was a part of the now non-existing process.

Comment: Not entirely true. Any read only content of the DLL may be only loaded once in physical memory but this is also true of multiple instance of an executable. Read/Write things like the data segment will be loaded for each instance of the DLL loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, a DLL is a machine code library that augments your executable with extra code, nothing more and nothing less. All threads, files and other resources belong to your executable even if they are create by functions in the DLL.

So when you executable dies, everything created by your executable dies.